# Cannot push_back() a struct into an std::vector<std::shared_ptr<theStruct>> theVector

Tags: c++

Hopefully my title isn't too confusing. I'm trying to write a sound manager for my game using SFML. I'm trying to replace my new/delete with the "smart pointer" std::shared_ptr. This is what I have so far.

```
/* SoundManager.h */
#ifndef SOUNDMANAGER_H
#define SOUNDMANAGER_H

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class SoundManager
{
    public:
        ~SoundManager();

        struct jteSound
        {
            sf::Sound snd;
            sf::SoundBuffer sndBuffer;
            std::string name;
        };

        //Load a new sound from path and store it in audio bank bnk.
        //Banks are simply std::vectors of type jteSound.
        void registerNewSound(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<jteSound>> &bnk, std::string path, std::string sndName);

        //Footsteps bank
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<jteSound>> bnkFootsteps;
};

#endif // SOUNDMANAGER_H

/* SoundManager.cpp */
#include "SoundManager.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

SoundManager::~SoundManager()
{
    /*
    //Cleanup each sound bank that we use.
    for (std::vector<jteSound*>::iterator it = bnkFootsteps.begin(); it != bnkFootsteps.end(); ++it) {
        delete *it;
    }
    */
}

void SoundManager::registerNewSound(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<jteSound>> &bnk, std::string path, std::string sndName)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    for (int i = counter; counter <i+1; counter++) {
        bnk.push_back(jteSound);
        bnk[i]->name = sndName;
        bnk[i]->sndBuffer.loadFromFile(path);
        bnk[i]->snd.setBuffer(bnk[i]->sndBuffer);
    }
}
```

`bnk.push_back(jteSound);` gives me a compiler error. If I remove the line, the program compiles, but crashes. I have tried things like `emplace_back()` or `jteSound*` or `new jteSound`, but nothing works. I always get a lengthy compiler error or immediate runtime crash. When I use regular pointers and new/delete, see https://bpaste.net/show/fa684f2f2d5e and https://bpaste.net/show/c74ac701ce7a, the code works as expected. Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the elements inside your `std::vector` is `std::shared_ptr<jteSound>` which means that `std::vector::push_back` will accept only instances of that type.

To make your code work you have two options. The first is using [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) helper function as follows:

```
bnk.push_back(std::make_shared<jteSound>());

// the equivalent counterpart is:
bnk.push_back(std::shared_ptr<jteSound>(new jteSound));
```

The second is using [`std::vector::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) as follows:

```
bnk.emplace(bnk.end(), new jteSound);
```

---

As the comments below warn, **using the second option is risky** because it can cause memory leak when the `new jteSound` succeeds but the `std::vector::emplace` has to reallocate memory and fails.

Comment: specialization and instantiation are different things.

Comment: The second would risk leaking memory if the `new jteSound` succeeds, but then the vector's `emplace_back` needs to reallocate storage and fails (and it happens that the `bad_alloc` exception is caught instead of calling `terminate`).